# Facebook app install ads show 0 install for android

Tags: android, facebook

We have two ads. one targetted to iOS user, one targetted to Android user.

Facebook dashboard shows that the two ads spent roughly the same amount (around 35$)

iOS ads has `152 app installs` whereas 
Android ads has `-- app installs`
[image]

I think something is wrong here.
I'm not sure how I should start debug this?

Please let me know if there's a better place to ask this question.

Comment: You are activating it on Android right ? "AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); " https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk

Comment: @sunilsunny Yes, I somehow missed it. Thank you! I can accept if you turn it into an answer.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.Hope it helps someone else too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable tracking for this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() { 
  super.onResume(); 
  AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); 
  // ...
}

// Optional: App Deactivation Event 
@Override
protected void onPause() { 
  super.onPause(); 
  AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}
```